# how to get a page owner feeds by facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to get a facebook page feeds using graph URL. but i want to get only the owner data ... i don't want anything not from the owner. i can do that using PHP. but i'm asking if i can do that using the same graph request.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use **/posts** instead of **/feed**